# Update device's firmware via BLE from web browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have to develop a webpage using React that can scan for Bluetooth devices nearby, connect to one and update its firmware using a file selected by the user.

I managed to scan and connect to devices but I cannot find a way to do the firmware update. Is it even possible?

Comment: Probably depends on the device. For Nordic devices, for example, https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-bluetooth-dfu.

Comment: Sure, it’s possible. The device has to support it, either natively or by building an OTA update system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.